# Possible to have predefined values on a template/only accept some values

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia

Is it possible to have predefined values on a template? I.e.

```
{{Infobox Employee
|age = {{{age}}}
|gender = {male,female}
|occupation = {nurse, doctor, caretaker}
}}
```

So whenever someone uses this template they have to chose either male or female and if neither is chosen nothing shows. Very much like a select in html.

Comment: Would it be possible to have an if-state that check 
    
    if(gender == male || female)
        gender = gender
   else
         gender=""

Comment: More like this: `{{#ifeq:{{{gender|}}}|male| Do something | Do something else}}`

Comment: And to answer you question: The closest you'll get is to print an error message if input is invalid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In core MediaWiki, you can make the template output an error or ignore unexpected parameters but cannot prevent the user from entering an invalid value. E.g. you can do something like this in the infobox:

```
{{#switch:{{{gender}}}
| male = Male
| female = Female
| #default = <span style="color:red">Invalid gender</span>[[Category:Pages with invalid template parameters]]
}}
```

(This example uses `#switch` from the [ParserFunctions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ParserFunctions) extension. You can do the same thing without ParserFunctions but it requires some complex and awkward template code.)

With the [TemplateData](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TemplateData) extension you can specify allowed values, but it will only affect editors which rely on TemplateData (e.g. [VisualEditor](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:VisualEditor)); it won't influence what someone can do with the template by plaintext editing.

The [Semantic Forms](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Semantic_Forms) extension can display an actual form for editing the infobox, with select boxes and whatever else you specify.